# Memory issue - InputStream/OutputStream

Tags: java

Nothing special, just frustrating. Using 1.4GB of memory on this ObjectInputStream$HandleTable$HandleList[]

[image: see picture for visualization]

I use the ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream to parse my file into a binary (.obj) file. So it does of course make sense, that this would appear. I do more or less just want to know wether or not there exists some kind of 'hack' to reduce this. Perhaps.

Have tried input.close() and output.close() but as my writing and reading are surrounded by try/catch {} those two method calls are redundant.

```
minlat = input.readFloat();
minlon = input.readFloat();
maxlat = input.readFloat();
maxlon = input.readFloat();
kdtreeCoastline = (KDTree) input.readObject();
kdtreeBicycle = (KDTree) input.readObject();

----

output.writeFloat(minlat);
output.writeFloat(minlon);
output.writeFloat(maxlat);
output.writeFloat(maxlon);
output.writeObject(kdtreeCoastline);
output.writeObject(kdtreeBicycle);
```

Not expecting this to be reduced to 0 bytes, but would just like to hear if anyone potentially would have an idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should look for a different (de)serialization mechanism, where you can stream data, and not all of the data needs to be kept in memory.

Comment: What tool did you use to display the heap usage?

Comment: The extra memory is used to correctly restore the object structure in the case that you have different pointers pointing to the same object. You do not seem to need that in this application. So you might get better results doing the (un)serialization yourself.

Comment: Are you using `try-with-resources` or just `try-catch`?

Comment: What is `KDTree` implementation you are using, custom one? That actually determines what a possible solution might be.

Comment: @yegodm it is own implementation

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Used VisualVM

Comment: @MoritzPetersen I'll take a look at that. Any recommendations?

Comment: With custom implementation you can likely override default serialization with `readExternal`/`writeExternal` in a way that avoids huge lookup tables in memory.

Answer (score 2):

1) Try read and write to output immediately, making object eligible for GC + ensure you use local variables not fields so temporary objects lifetime is not extended to lifetime of parser

2) `try/catch {} those two method calls are redundant.` Try/catch does not close resource unless you use `try-with` syntax (e.g. `try (input = new ObjectInputStream(...))`)

Comment: Actually I did use try-with block of course. But thanks, which of course was why they were redundant. My bad. Been a long day

Answer (score 1):

The `HandleTable` memory consumption suggests that you are not closing the `ObjectInputStream` correctly. `ObjectInputStream.close()` will internally clear the `HandleTable`, it's not redundant and must be called to clear handles.

Either use `try-with-resources` or call `close()` it in `finally`. You shouldn't depend on the GC to do the work for you here.

Comment: A quick query: you said "You shouldn't depend on the GC to do the work for you here." But what other option is there? When you close the file, the internal implementation of the close() method will "internally clear the HandleTable" using your own words. But what does "internally clear the HandleTable" actually mean? Presumably it means deleting all object references to the HandleTable and allowing it to be garbage-collected - so ultimately still depending on the GC to do the work? Maybe the reason the OP sees the HandleTable still allocated is that the GC hasn't got around to reclaiming yet?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with default serialization is that it needs to register additional headers (class to be serialized, etc) as well as reference (as I remember, the `ObjectOutputStream` ensure that if instance A and B depends on instance C, then it will still be true when using `ObjectInputStream`; eg: you must not have A depending on C and B depending on C'). This would take a little bit of space.

- You may cir-convene using `DataInputStream`and `DataOutputStream` in place of `ObjectOutputStream` / `ObjectInputStream`, although your file format will be rather specific to your need and it'll be more sensitive on data format change.
- You can also try to implements the [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/Serializable.html) *hidden* methods `writeObject` and `readObject` (see link) to customize the serialized form of your object.